# PowerShell to find usernames that have access

Tags: powershell, batch-file, icacls

I am trying to get the ACL of a set of folders to see if a specific user is listed

For example

```
 Users
 |
  ---Person1
  ---Person2
  ---Person3
```

Person1 to 3 are home folders. We recently ran an icacls command to modify the folder permission. Some of them have the owner set to "IT Employee" instead of Person1

If it was only 3 folders, I would do this manually. However there are at least 1000 folders and manually would not be feasible to get the data back in a timely manner.

Basically there are 6 IT Employees and I want to make sure their name is not in any Person home folder (or it's sub folders). If it is there then I want to be able to remove them or at least get a console log.

I am using PowerShell 2 on Windows Server 2008

I can also execute VBScript or JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this to get you started. I'm not connected to a network with a file server atm., so I'm not sure if `Owner` and `IdentityReference` contains `DOMAIN\Username` or SID (this happends for non-exisiting users, ex. deleted ones). I get `<DOMAIN or ComputerName>\Username` when I run it on m local machine. You may have to modify it to handle that.

```
$rootpath = "c:\users"

#Get all folders
Get-ChildItem -Path $rootpath -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }
#Get ACL for the folders
Get-Acl |
#Find ACLs with IT Employee-reference
Where-Object {

    #Check if owner matches 'IT Employee' or ACL Access rules contains 'IT Employee'
    if(($_.Owner -match 'IT Employee') -or ($_.Access | Where-Object { $_.IdentityReference.Value -match 'IT Employee' })) { $_ }

} |
#Process
ForEach-Object {

    #Show folderpath...
    $_.Path

    #Here you could access the ACL-object $_, modify it (change owner/remove access rules) and save it by using 'Set-Acl -Path $_.Path -AclObject $_'   etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I added a line of code to the "ForEach" loop to display the status of each child folder. but it doesn't appear to work. Get-Acl -Path $_.Path

Comment: Where and why did you add `Get-Acl -Path $_.Path`? Please update your question with a sample and the new error.